# Starting an activity X from activity X in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, popup

I have an an android application that based on the type of job starts either activity X or Y.
Now if I have a series of jobs like X1, X2, Y1, X3, Y2
My application will call the activity X. When the user submits from that activity the same activity is started again. Next when he submits again the activity Y needs to be started. I see a pop up in the android device asking "complete using" with 2 options with my android application name.
**I do not want to see this pop up.** 
This is how I start an activity.

```
if(DataType.X.equals(transaction)){
    Intent i = new Intent ( "android.intent.action.X");
    startActivity(i);
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent ( "android.intent.action.Y");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to avoid popup, you may do it in this way

```
if(DataType.X.equals(transaction)){
    Intent i = new Intent (getBaseContext(), activity_X.class);
    startActivity(i);
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent (getBaseContext(), activity_Y.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas. It worked. On the emulator at least. Haven't yet tested on a mobile device. Can you tell me when if it appropriate to startActivity using the way you say it and the way I have done

Comment: if you want to launch activities which are available in your own application, then its more convenient to call it in the way I've mentioned. But if you want to call an activity system-wide depending on the category it suits, then call it in the way you did previously.